# Cannot Lookup from InitialContext Queue that has same name with another Topic

Tags: java, jms, tibco-ems, initial-context

This line of code produces an exception

```
Queue queue = (Queue) initialCtx.lookup("sample");

javax.naming.CannotProceedException: Name 'sample' is ambiguous: both a topic and a queue exist
at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:715)[tibjms-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:489)[tibjms-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)[:1.6.0_45]
```

Background info:

- I have tried with another queue name, and it works fine.
- The problem with this "sample" queue is there is another topic with exactly the same name

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Two objects in JNDI with the same name is the issue; can you change the name of one object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured topic and queue with the same name in `TIBCO`, you can add `$queues.`  or `$topics.` prefix and it should work, example :

```
initialCtx.lookup("$queues.sample")
```