# Jmeter javax.naming.CannotProceedException: Name 'sample' is ambiguous: both a topic and a queue exist

Tags: java, jmeter, message-queue, publish-subscribe, jms-topic

I am trying to listen for a message on an error-log queue in order to test a couple error scenarios for our system. However, we have a topic and a queue that share the same name... Is there a way to specify which one Jmeter should listen to? For example, only the queue or only the topic.

I am getting the following sampler error:

> javax.naming.CannotProceedException: Name 'sample' is ambiguous: both
>   a topic and a queue exist

Comment: try `/topic/sample` or `/queue/sample`

Comment: It didn't work. I tried doing this in the subscribe sampler in the destination and it doesn't recognize the queue or topic name. I also tried to use a Point to Point sampler since I figured it would assume that I am referring to the QUEUE since it won't work with a Queue <--> Topic but still gives me the same 'ambiguous' error.

Comment: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/08/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-publishsubscribe-to-jms-queuestopics-in-wso2-message-broker/ may be it can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31337316/2674303 try to add $

Comment: which message broker do you use?